# "TeX Live Manager" send an error with the message "Cannot determine release"

Tags: texlive

I have just installed TeX Live 2015 using "install-tl-WINDOWS.bat".

When I click in "TeX Live Manager", I get an error with the message "Cannot determine release".

But if I execute "tlmgr --gui" in a command line, it works perfectly.

what is the mistake?

Comment: Update your installation at command prompt with `tlmgr update --all`, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the file `release-texlive.txt` in your TeX Live 2015 folder , e.g. `C:\texlive\2015\release-texlive.txt`, is missing, use this file:

ftp://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/release-texlive.txt

At the time of my writing, the content of this file is:

```
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2015

This file is public domain.  It is read by install-tl --version, tlmgr --version, and texconfig conf, and a final line appended with the precise    version number by tl-update-images during a build.

The following blank line at the end helps avoid confusing output when used    directly from svn, so don't delete it.


texlive-20150523
```

I found this solution after reading this [message by Adam Maxwell](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.live/36925).

Comment: thanks. dont have solution without internet?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "without internet". Just create a file named release-texlive.txt with your text editor and copy the contents highlighted in my post.

Comment: @HadiSafiaghdam Why would you want one? Without internet, what would you do with TeX Live Manager?

Comment: i send answer because i need to send screen shot to forum.very thanks.

 1. i do that.
but when i run "Tex Live Manager" from all programs, i get this error:
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dgqXa.png
and i must click on cancel to run "texlive manager"
 2. do not  exist any way to solve this problem without this txt file? for example with tug, texlive publisher, ...?

very thanks